# CardView in RecyclerView resizing itself when it comes in to view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, cardview

I have made a RecyclerView that holds a number of different CardViews. When the RecyclerView loads up for the first time, the cards that start on-screen, visible in the recycler view are the correct size, but when they scroll off-screen, the next time they come back on-screen they have been resized and are an incorrect size.

Video of it in action: https://gfycat.com/gifs/detail/SoupyPowerlessFulmar

**LocationsListFragment:**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_locations_list, container, false);
    adapter = new LocationsAdapter(mParam1);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_locations);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    L
```

inearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

```
    return v;
}
```

**LocationsViewHolder:**

```
public class LocationsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

private ImageView locationImage;
private TextView locationName;
private TextView locationAddress;

public LocationsViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    locationName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.location_name);
    locationAddress = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.location_address);
    locationImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.location_image);
}

public void updateUI(HashMap<String, String > place){
    locationName.setText(place.get("name"));
}

}
```

**LocationsAdapter:**

```
public class LocationsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

private ImageView locationImage;
private TextView locationName;
private TextView locationAddress;

public LocationsViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    locationName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.location_name);
    locationAddress = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.location_address);
    locationImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.location_image);
}
public void updateUI(HashMap<String, String > place){
    locationName.setText(place.get("name"));
}

}
```

**card_location.xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/card">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="274dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_margin="15dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Test"
                android:textColor="#2f2f2f"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:id="@+id/location_name"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Address Goes Here"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/location_address"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_restaurant_black_24dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:id="@+id/location_image"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I think that should be all of the information needed. If there is anything else you need to see please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: change height of cardview as wrap content =>   android:layout_height="wrap_parent"

Answer (score 0):

change height of cardview as wrap content

```
android:layout_height="wrap_parent"
```